# How to tile the contents of a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos, calayer

I would like to tile a CGImage across a CALayer, but it seems to only want to stretch it.

The example code:

```
 self.background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Background.png"];
 [documentDisplay.layer setContents: self.background.CGImage];
```

I would like to avoid subclassing if I could.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a color with a pattern image and set that as the background color of the layer.

To do that you need wrap your `CGImage` in a `CGPattern` and make a `CGColor` from it.

```
// callback for CreateImagePattern.
static void drawPatternImage (void *info, CGContextRef ctx)
{
    CGImageRef image = (CGImageRef) info;
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, 
                       CGRectMake(0,0, CGImageGetWidth(image),CGImageGetHeight(image)),
                       image);
}

// callback for CreateImagePattern.
static void releasePatternImage( void *info )
{
    CGImageRelease((CGImageRef)info);
}

//assume image is the CGImage you want to assign as the layer background
int width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
int height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
static const CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = {0, &drawPatternImage, &releasePatternImage};
CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate (image,
                        CGRectMake (0, 0, width, height),
                        CGAffineTransformMake (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                        width,
                        height,
                        kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
                        true,
                        &callbacks);
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
CGFloat components[1] = {1.0};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateWithPattern(space, pattern, components);
CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
CGPatternRelease(pattern);
yourLayer.backgroundColor = color; //set your layer's background to the image
CGColorRelease(color);
```

This code is modified from the GeekGameBoard sample code.

Comment: I just noticed +colorWithPatternImage in UIColor, is this thing similar?

Comment: Yes, this should do the same thing, although I haven't tested it. `UIColor` has not always been available in iPhone OS so I'm used to using the `CGColor` methods.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it seems to me that using images as `backgroundColor` breaks the ability to animate it. (I have posted a question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605618/core-animation-animation-doesnt-work).)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made a mistake by taking the image's color space and using it for the `CGColorCreateWithPattern` call. It does not draw anything in this case.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this solution. The image is correctly drawn, and it is not upside down, but it seems to be drawn from the bottom, because when I resize the window, the bottom is fixed, while the top is moving. Do you know how can I have the opposite working ?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest code to accomplish this is:

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_tile"]].CGColor;
```

Comment: Ah, right. I'm pretty iOS-centric. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `colorWithPatternImage:` appears to be available in iOS, see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithPatternImage:)

Answer (score 3):

This is rather simpler. But beware, this is a private API, use at your own risk.

Setup as follows

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CA_EXTERN NSString * const kCAContentsScalingRepeat;

@interface CALayer (CALayerAdditions)
@property(copy) NSString *contentsScaling;
@end
```

Then just do this

```
[myLayer setContentsScaling:kCAContentsScalingRepeat];
```

Comment: As @sdsykes mentioned, this is a private API and must be used carefully (if at all). In case you are wondering what the possible values are, the only ones I could find were kCAContentsScalingStretch and kCAContentsScalingRepeat. A bit of trivia :)

Answer (score 0):

You could employ CGContextDrawTiledImage method for this