# How do I draw a tiled pattern image in a CATiledLayer?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm following the instructions outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520978/how-to-tile-the-contents-of-a-calayer/2521046#2521046) to fill a layer with a pattern in Core Graphics. When the layer is a CALayer subclass, the drawing works fine. However, when the layer is a CATiledLayer subclass, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at runtime.

```
static void drawPatternImage (void *info, CGContextRef ctx)
{
    CGImageRef image = (CGImageRef) info;
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, 
                       CGRectMake(0,0, CGImageGetWidth(image),CGImageGetHeight(image)),
                       image); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here :(
}

static void releasePatternImage( void *info )
{
    CGImageRelease((CGImageRef)info);
}

// pattern creation
int width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
int height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
static const CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = {0, &drawPatternImage, &releasePatternImage};
CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate (image,
                        CGRectMake (0, 0, width, height),
                        CGAffineTransformMake (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                        width,
                        height,
                        kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
                        true,
                        &callbacks);
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
CGFloat components[1] = {1.0};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateWithPattern(space, pattern, components);
CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
CGPatternRelease(pattern);
theLayer.backgroundColor = color;
CGColorRelease(color);
```

What do I need to do to draw a patterned image in a CATiledLayer subclass?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this code. It doesn't crash, the image is correctly drawn, and it is not upside down, but it seems to be drawn from the bottom, because when I resize the window, the bottom is fixed, while the top is moving. Do you know how can I have the opposite working ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i use "CGContextDrawTiledImage" in the "drawLayer" method for a CATiledLayer class:

in .h:

```
@interface StarView : UIView {
    UIImage *imgTextureCarta;
}
```

in .m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString* imagePath = [ [ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aTexture" ofType:@"png"];
    imgTextureCarta = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
    [imgTextureCarta retain];
    CGImageRef texureCarta;
    texureCarta = (imgTextureCarta.CGImage);
}



-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context{
    CGImageRef texureCarta;
    texureCarta = (imgTextureCarta.CGImage);
    CGRect bounds = layer.bounds;
    CGContextSetBlendMode (context, 0);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, layer.bounds);
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0, 128, 120), texureCarta);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [imgTextureCarta release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: This will draw the image upside down.  You can flip it before you draw: `CGContextScaleCTM (ctx, 1, -1);`