# How to interact with layer-backed views on the Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, calayer

I am designing a user interface containing several labels and text fields. I would like to style the UI like this:

1. setting a background pattern for the content view of my `NSWindow`
2. adding a custom icon to the background in the upper left corner

I solved the first problem by making the content view a *layer-backed view* as described in [Apple's documentation of `NSView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html):

> A layer-backed view is a view that is backed by a Core Animation layer. Any drawing done by the view is the cached in the backing layer. You configured a layer-backed view by simply invoking `setWantsLayer:` with a value of `YES`. The view class will automatically create the a backing layer for you, and you use the view class’s drawing mechanisms. **When using layer-backed views you should never interact directly with the layer.**
>
> A layer-hosting view is a view that contains a Core Animation layer that you intend to manipulate directly. You create a layer-hosting view by instantiating an instance of a Core Animation layer class and setting that layer using the view’s `setLayer:` method. After doing so, you then invoke `setWantsLayer:` with a value of `YES`. **When using a layer-hosting view you should not rely on the view for drawing, nor should you add subviews to the layer-hosting view.**

and then generating a `CGColorRef` out of a `CGPattern` which draws my `CGImage`:

```
NSView *mainView = [[self window]contentView];
[mainView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

To set the background image as a pattern I used the answer from [How to tile the contents of a CALayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520978/how-to-tile-the-contents-of-a-calayer) here on SO to get the first task done.

However for the second task, adding the icon I used the code below:

```
CGImageRef iconImage = NULL;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon_128" ofType:@"png"];
if(path != nil) {
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageURL);
    iconImage = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider,NULL,FALSE,kCGRenderingIntentDefault); 
    CFRelease(provider);
}
CALayer *iconLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
// layer is the mainView's layer
CGRect layerFrame = layer.frame;
CGFloat iconWidth = 128.f;
iconLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, CGRectGetHeight(layerFrame)-iconWidth, 128.f, 128.f);
iconLayer.contents = (id)iconImage;
CGImageRelease(iconImage);
[layer insertSublayer:iconLayer  atIndex:0];
[iconLayer release];
```

### The Questions

1. I am not sure if I am violating Apple's restrictions concerning *layer-backed* views that you should never interact directly with the layer. When setting the layer's background color *I am* interacting directly with the layer or am I mistaken here?
2. I have a bad feeling about interacting with the layer hierarchy of a *layer-backed* view directly and inserting a new layer like I did for my second task. Is this possible or also violating Apple's guidelines? I want to point out that this content view of course has several subviews such as labels, a text view and buttons.
3. It seems to me that just using one single *layer-hosting* `NSView` seems to be the cleanest solution. All the text labels could then be added as `CATextLayers` etc. However if I understand Apple's documentation correctly I cannot add any controls to the view anymore. Would I have to code all the controls myself in custom `CALayers` to get it working? Sounds like reinventing the wheel *de luxe*. I also have no idea how one would code a `NSTextField` solely in CoreAnimation.

Any advice on how split designing user interfaces with CoreAnimation and standard controls is appreciated.

**Please note that I am talking about the Mac here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no layer backing needed IMHO:

for 1. I do a pattern image

```
NSImage *patternImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"pattern"];
[window setBackgroungdColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage]];
```

for 2. add an NSImageView as a subview of the contentview

```
NSImageView *v = ...
[[window contentView] addSubview:v];
```

---

*on mac some views dont respond nicely IF layer backed*
:: e.g. pdfview

Answer (score 0):

Make a superview container A. Add a subview B to A for all your NSView needs (buttons, etc.). Add a subview C to A for all your Core Animation needs.

Edit:
Even better: use superview A for all your NSView needs and one subview C for your Core Animation needs, ignoring view B altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is problematic as the layering behavior of sibling views is undefined. See the [View programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW1).

Comment: That's a chewy link. Perhaps you can direct me to which section that says a child view cannot have layers attached to it. If they cannot, then how could any view have layers?

Comment: No that is not the point I am trying to make. The clipping and redrawing behavior of sibling views is undefined. That means that in your edit you get in trouble if subview C overlaps with B

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't know what exactly your program does, but instead of "reinventing the wheel de luxe" and figuring out how to code text fields and buttons with CALayers, maybe you should reinvent another wheel and figure out how to get your background pattern and icon on your view without using layers, or maybe concede and not have your CALayers overlap your views.

Comment: Yes that is basically what I have done. I worked with custom views and drawing everything using Quartz.