# What's wrong with the layer-backed view in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, layer

I got a problem confused me for a long time when I develop a mac application.

I have a view named `containerView` which is a layer-backed view, that is I set its `wantsLayer` to true. And I have a another view controller that contains a image view that will change its image later. And I added this view controller's view to the containerView, and a weird thing occurred. The image view's image won't show. But when I click a certain button, the image comes out. When I set the containerView's `wantsLayer` to false, everything goes fine. It seems the view can't update when it's in a layer-backed view.

I have googled related problem but I couldn't find one that could resolve my problem. And I have tried to set the view's `layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .onSetNeedsDisplay` and nothing happened.

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896224/how-to-interact-with-layer-backed-views-on-the-mac)?

Comment: @Droppy Thanks for the link, but it seems can't solve my problem.