# How to set a tiled background image for a CALayer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I set the background for the IKBrowserView the background is resized according to the view size: is there a way to set it as tiled image, repeated but never resized ?

```
NSImage*    backgroundImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"wood-bg2.jpg"];
CALayer*    aLayer = [CALayer layer];
//aLayer.contents = backgroundImage;

CIColor *ci = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage]];
CGColorSpaceRef cs = [ci colorSpace];
const CGFloat *comps = [ci components];
CGColorRef cgColor = CGColorCreate(cs, comps);

aLayer.backgroundColor = cgColor;
[itemThumbnailImageBrowserView setBackgroundLayer:aLayer];
```

I've tried both the commented out code and the current code, but none work.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a method of `NSColor`:

```
+ (NSColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(NSImage *)image
```

So you can do something like this:

```
NSImage*    backgroundImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"wood-bg2.jpg"];
CALayer*    aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage] CGColor]; // - (CGColor) CGColor; is only available in OS X 10.8 and later
[itemThumbnailImageBrowserView setBackgroundLayer:aLayer];
```

---

## Update for OS X 10.8 and lower

**Convert `NSColor` to `CGColor` (not tested):**

```
CIColor *ci = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage]];
CGColorSpaceRef cs = [ci colorSpace];
const CGFloat *comps = [ci components];
CGColorRef cgColor = CGColorCreate(cs, comps);
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the colorWithPatternImage line gives me this warning:passing argument 1 from incompatible pointer type

Comment: I don't get why, because I'm passing the NSImage as you wrote, which is the correct content type

Comment: Ah, it is because backgroundColor takes a CGColor and not a NSColor

Comment: That makes sense... Try `aLayer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage] CGColor];`

Comment: CGColor works only the OSX 10.8 the latest Mountain Lion. Unfortunately I'm on Lion. Do you know any easy way to convert it?

Comment: Ok thanks. The code runs, but I'm getting weird results: http://cl.ly/image/3r2d3C0I2b1C. I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: If I use instead the line I've commented out, it works but of course it resizes with the view.

Comment: I like the result, don't you? Seems like it's not converting properly. Maybe have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520978/how-to-tile-the-contents-of-a-calayer It doesn't use `NSColor` and creates a `CGPattern`. Little bit more code, but it seems working.

Comment: Thanks. I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the callback method  drawPatternImage at this line: CGContextDrawImage(ctx,  CGRectMake(0,0, CGImageGetWidth(image),CGImageGetHeight(image)), image); Not sure why....

Comment: All objects in that method seems to be correctly allocated. I don't have nil objects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24378/discussion-between-fabio-poloni-and-patrick)