# Converting a NSColor created with colorWithPatternImage to CGColor?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've tried several times to convert a NSColor created from an image with colorWithPatternImage  back and forward to CGColor. It always fails, I get weird bad results.

I'm wondering if the conversion works for colors that are generated with tiled images, or it simply impossible. This is how I convert the colors:

```
-(CGColorRef) CIColorToCGColor: (CIColor *) ciColor {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = [ciColor colorSpace];
    const CGFloat *components = [ciColor components];
    CGColorRef cgColor = CGColorCreate (colorSpace, components);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return cgColor;
}
```

...

```
CIColor *ciColor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor: [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage]];
CGColorRef cgColor = [self CIColorToCGColor: ciColor];
[ciColor release];
```

Comment: Why do you convert the `NSColor` to `CIColor` first? `NSColor` has a method `CGColor`, does that no work?

Comment: How do you know that the result is wrong?

Comment: @MartinR That method is available in Mountain Lion only

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri This is how it looks like: http://cl.ly/image/3r2d3C0I2b1C

Comment: @Patrick An image may have many colors, this way you're just taking a single pixel of it.

Comment: What's the alternative method for 10.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do this a few weeks ago. I found this answer which basically solves the problem,
[How to tile the contents of a CALayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520978/how-to-tile-the-contents-of-a-calayer)

Here it is in a more convenient form,

```
// callback for CreateImagePattern.
static void DrawPatternImage (void *info, CGContextRef ctx) {
    CGImageRef image = (CGImageRef) info;
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx,
                       CGRectMake(0,0, CGImageGetWidth(image),CGImageGetHeight(image)),
                       image);
}

// callback for CreateImagePattern.
static void ReleasePatternImage( void *info ) {
    CGImageRelease((CGImageRef)info);
}

CGColorRef CreateCGColorWithPatternFromNSImage( NSImage *image ) {
    /* User needs to release the color  */

    NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
    CFDataRef cfImageData = CFBridgingRetain(imageData);
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(cfImageData, NULL);
    CGImageRef cgImage =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
    CFRelease(cfImageData);
    CFRelease(source);


    //assume image is the CGImage you want to assign as the layer background
    CGFloat width = [image size].width;
    CGFloat height = [image size].height;
    static const CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = {0, &DrawPatternImage, &ReleasePatternImage};
    CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate (cgImage,
                                            CGRectMake (0, 0, width, height),
                                            CGAffineTransformMake (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                                            width,
                                            height,
                                            kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
                                            true,
                                            &callbacks);
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
    CGFloat components[1] = {1.0};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateWithPattern(space, pattern, components);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    CGPatternRelease(pattern);
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSColor has a function that lets you get the pattern that the color was created with:
`-[NSColor patternImage]`. Use that method, convert the image to a CGImage (if you prefer), and make a pattern CGColor.

Edit: Another way to do this is, if you are using 10.8 or later, to use the `+[NSColor colorWithCGColor:]` class method. However, it may not work %100 of the time, so check for nil.