# Controlling orientation of pattern in CGStroke

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, cgcontext

I'm attempting to create a 'patterned brush stroke' effect in my app. I'm achieving this using `CGContextStrokePath` with a patterned `UIColor`. This is giving me the below problem.

When I draw a straight line, it works fantastically, e.g:

[image]

Yet when I draw a diagonal stroke, I get this:

[image]

Whereas I'm actually aiming for this:

[image]

(The difference in orientation of the pattern is the issue here, not my shoddy image cropping!)

What I've been trying to do thus far, is look for a way to control the orientation in which the pattern is tiled/displayed, yet I haven't managed to figure out a method to do this. Can anyone enlighten me, or tell me how I should be doing it instead?

Current code included for completeness below.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    // get the current context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Create a pattern
    NSString* theFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"iceliteTrial.png" ofType: nil];
    UIImage* theGrassPatternImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: theFilePath];
    UIColor* iceLitePattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: theGrassPatternImage];
    CGSize phase = CGSizeMake(self.lineStart.x, self.lineStart.y-30);
    CGContextSetPatternPhase(context,phase);

    // set the stroke color and width
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, iceLitePattern.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 60.0);

    // move to your first point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.lineStart.x, self.lineStart.y);

   // add a line to your second point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.lineEnd.x, self.lineEnd.y);

    // tell the context to draw the stroked line
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

Comment: You do `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: theFilePath];` every time draw rect is called. This will adversely affect performance. You should load it once when the view loads and save it in an instance variable.

Comment: Good shout - thank you. I apologise - it's definitely work in progress code!

Comment: No prob. I had the same issue with loading custom image pins on a MKMapView...with 800+ pins. I figured that one out real fast :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using CGContext I would recommend switching to using a CAShapeLayer.  I used this approach in one of my apps like this:

```
//call this on every drawRect: call.
-(void)makeLineLayer:(CALayer *)layer{
    CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *linePath=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [linePath moveToPoint:self.lineStart];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:self.lineEnd];
    [linePath setLineWidth:60.0];

    line.path=linePath.CGPath;
    line.fillColor = nil;
    line.opacity = 1.0;
    [layer addSublayer:line];
}
```

This will give you the line between the two points. From Here I would recommend adding a `CALayer` to the `CAShapeLayer` and set its `contents` property to your image. Here is [a link to an article describing how to tile an image in a CALayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520978/how-to-tile-the-contents-of-a-calayer).  Then you wold need to calculate the angle of the `CAShapeLayer` and rotate the `CALayer` by that angle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @67cherries, I'm currently looking into it, but having issues implementing it - it's the first time I've touched CALayers. Posted a question at the below link with what I'm struggling with, don't know if you'd be able to advise there as well?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21608376/1768779

Comment: Thank you. In the end, I did something along these lines, involving using the CAShapeLayer as a mask. I never want to do any trigonometry again!  Thanks for your help.